# FFT Implementation issues (GPU Shader)

Tags: glsl, shader, signal-processing, fft

I am trying to implement an FFT in a shader to run on the GPU. I grabbed the algorithm from here: https://github.com/jbouny/fft-ocean ... nShader.js

However, when implemented and compared with other FFT objects (which I'm doing in max/msp) the results of the above algorithm don't seem to match at all.

Would anyone be able to tell me if there is an issue with the algorithm or implementation? If nothing is wrong with the algorithm then there must be an issue with how I am sending the values or something...

Some points to consider:

1. I am performing the FFT on audio samples which are 1D instead of an image. The input I'm sending it is a window of 1024 audio samples, (ie vec4(sample,0,0,0) ) the dimensions are 1024x1.
2. I don't really understand the Subtransform size and it's hard to find clear info about it from google searching, so I am not sure if I'm setting it correctly. It seems to make a big difference in the value output!
3. I set the transform size as the FFT size, is that correct?

Here is the algorithm implemented in my shader:

```
const float TWO_PI_NEG = -6.2831853072;
varying vec2 texcoord0;
uniform sampler2D tex0;
uniform float fftSize = 1024;
uniform float subtransformSize = 4;
uniform float subtransformSizeHalf = 2;
uniform float horizontal = 1;
float fftSizeHalf = fftSize * 0.5;



//
vec2 multiplyComplex (vec2 a, vec2 b) {
    return vec2(a[0] * b[0] - a[1] * b[1], a[1] * b[0] + a[0] * b[1]);
}


//GPU FFT using a Stockham formulation
vec4 fft (
    sampler2D src, 
    vec2 coord,
    float transformSize, 
    float transformSizeHalf,
    float subtransformSize,
    float subtransformSizeHalf,
    float horizontal
) {
    float index;
    if (horizontal == 1) {
        index = coord.x * transformSize - 0.5;
    } else {
        index = coord.y * transformSize - 0.5;
    }

    float evenIndex = floor(index / subtransformSize) * subtransformSizeHalf + mod(index, subtransformSizeHalf);

    //transform two complex sequences simultaneously
    vec4 even;
    vec4 odd;
    if (horizontal == 1) {
        even = texture2D(src, vec2(evenIndex + 0.5, gl_FragCoord.y) / transformSize).rgba;
        odd = texture2D(src, vec2(evenIndex + transformSizeHalf + 0.5, gl_FragCoord.y) / transformSize).rgba;
    } else {
        even = texture2D(src, vec2(gl_FragCoord.x, evenIndex + 0.5) / transformSize).rgba;
        odd = texture2D(src, vec2(gl_FragCoord.x, evenIndex + transformSizeHalf + 0.5) / transformSize).rgba;
    }

    float twiddleArgument1D = TWO_PI_NEG * (index / subtransformSize);
    vec2 twiddle1D = vec2(cos(twiddleArgument1D), sin(twiddleArgument1D));

    vec2 outputA = even.xy + multiplyComplex(twiddle1D, odd.xy);  //even.xy
    vec2 outputB = even.zw + multiplyComplex(twiddle1D, odd.zw); //even.zw
    return vec4(outputA, outputB);
}



//
void main(void){
    gl_FragColor = fft(tex0, texcoord0, fftSize, fftSizeHalf, subtransformSize, subtransformSizeHalf, 1.);
}
```

Thanks for any help!!

When I send sine tones through it the output is quite unexpected! I tried visualizing the polar coordinate, which should just show energy in the bin(s) of the sine's fundamental frequency, but instead the values are that of a repeating window at the frequency of the transformSize/subTransformSize/2 . That same window is seen with noise values as well

Comment: FYI I was told this algo needs to be recursive or iterated and was linked some solutions in GPU so I think I'll be ok! If anyone is curious these are the links: shadertoy.com/view/lsVXWt and github.com/dli/waves/blob/master/simulation.js#L566-L593